# Set focus to EditText after dismissDialog

Tags: android

I've some deprecated code I need to fix. 
After a dialog (showdialog) gets dismissed I want an edittext to get focused, text selected and keyboard up. That does not happen with this code.

With this code, there is no focus but the text gets selected.

```
...
alert.setPositiveButton(getString(android.R.string.ok), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    EditText txtE = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ORE);
                    dismissDialog(DIALOG_NO_E);
                    txtE.selectAll();
                    txtE.requestFocus();                        
                }
            });
...
```

Suggestions?

Comment: first dismiss the dialog and then set txtE.requestFocus();

Comment: simply Use `RequestFocus()`.

Comment: Tried to move it around, didnt work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding this after requestfocus made it work however. But it does not feel right.

```
txtE.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager keyboard = (android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager) getSystemService(android.content.Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                            keyboard.showSoftInput(txtE, 0);
                        }
                    }, 200);
```

End result

```
...
alert.setPositiveButton(getString(android.R.string.ok), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                    dismissDialog(DIALOG_NO_E);
                    txtE.selectAll();
                    txtE.requestFocus();                        
                }
            });
txtE.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager keyboard = (android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager) getSystemService(android.content.Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                                keyboard.showSoftInput(txtE, 0);
                            }
                        }, 200);
...
```

If someone has a better solution or an answer to why I have to do it like this, I'll give you the points for the answer latest on monday.

For this to work thou, I had to create the `txtE` as a static variable initialized in the constructor. That didnt feel good at all in my soul. So, if anyone has a better idea that works, do tell.